# QTP - Scope of files associated with called actions

Tags: qtp

Can somebody please let me know how the following fundamental thing works in QTP

I am calling Action 1 from Action 2. Action 1 has some associated libraries(.qfl). Should I associate library files associated with Action 1 in Action 2 as well? When I run Action 2, it calls Action 1 but the function call associated with Action 1 is not executed.

my questions

1)Please help me understand how QTP works while calling one action from other

2) If it the case that I should associate the library files in action 2 as well, should I associate everything (Recovery Scenarios, library files, config files, Shared repository files etc) that are associated with Action 1 in  Action 2 as well?

Regards

Srinivas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you. Please post what code you've tried so far. Establish a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Functions are common for entire test. You must attach all functions, recovery scenarios to main test. Object repositories must be attached to every action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach All library files with both the Actions from Files->Settings->Resources Options.As well as OR if you are using Common Objects in both Actions.

There are two ways of calling an action from another action.
1)At the end of one action.
2)At the desired step in one action.

If you are calling the action at the end of another action than the calling of both the Actions is done by 'Action 0' by default and in sequential manner.

And suppose you are calling Action 2 from Action 1 at any particular location than the call to Action 2 is inserted at that point only.